# Step function integral inequality

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality, hilbert-spaces, integral-inequality

I would like to prove the following inequality:
$$\langle f,Id \rangle^2  \leq \langle f,1 \rangle^2$$

where $f$ is a step function of the form $f(s)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^N f_i \mathbb{1}_{I(i)}(s)$, $f_i\in \mathbb{R}$, and $I(i)=\left[\frac{i-1}{N};\frac{i}{N}\right]$ for $i\in{1,...,N}$.

$\langle . \rangle$ denotes the scalar product in $\mathbb{L}^2 ([0,1])$ i.e $\langle f,g \rangle = \int_0^1 f(x)g(x)dx$.

I have already tried to use the decomposition $1=(1-Id)+Id$ and then developing the square, but I don't know where to go from there . Any ideas would be much appreciated!

Comment: If we take $N=2$ and $f_1=-1$, $f_2=1$ we get that $\langle f,1\rangle=0$ but the left side is $1/4$. Also works for every $N$ odd and taking $f_i=(-1)^i$, unless you missed the condition $f_i\geq 0$ in that case, this follows by doing the computations.

Comment: Just a little correction: "Also works for every $N$ **even**".